# jQuery if statement syntax with simple function

Tags: jquery, function, syntax, responsive-design

I'm trying to modify a simple orbit.js setting (using zurb foundation 3 framework), with an if statement to hide captions responsively.  The original on load function is working, the resize function isn't.  I know I'm doing something fundamentally wrong - pray tell me what it is please?

```
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#featured').orbit(
         {
         timer:false,
         }
        );
    });

   $(window).resize(function(){
     if ( $("#jq-mq-flag ").css("float") == "none") {

        $('#featured').orbit(
         {
         captions:false
         }
        );
    });
```

Comment: I'm new to this folks - apparently this is off-topic.  We have solved the overarching problem, through other means. I am grateful for Rituraj's syntactical correction which I will call a resolution of the  issue. (Most of my attempts to get into jquery have tripped over it's syntax in a way I haven't with others.) If there is a better place for me to be looking for this kind of issue resolution, I'm all ears. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   $(window).resize(function(){
     if ( $("#jq-mq-flag ").css("float") == "none") {

        $('#featured').orbit(
         {
         captions:false
         });
    }//you forget }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response Rituraj The script isn't breaking now, but the window resize function still isn't firing the caption:false statement (which does work in it's normal on load context). Any thoughts on a better way of handling the responsive media query aspect here? (am currently trying to sense a dummy style's property change)

Comment: see your orbit plugin for details or share with us the plugin url